# Trouble updating PHP version for CLI and Apache on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have multiple PHP versions (8.1/8.2/8.3) installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, and I'm trying to switch between them using the `sudo update-alternatives --config PHP` command. However, I'm facing an issue where the CLI version changes successfully, but the PHP version on my Apache server remains unchanged when I visit my project URL in the browser.

I've attempted various solutions, including:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php${version}
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

I've also restarted FPM, but none of these solutions seem to work. I'd appreciate any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using mod_php or php-fpm?

Comment: i am using php-fpm

Comment: You're changing the version of mod_php. I don't know how php-fpm is configured in your system, but you're failing to change that. It's typically a path in some *.conf file.

Comment: Actually, it answered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497120/trouble-updating-php-version-used-by-apache-on-ubuntu-22-04/1497153#1497153